# Match multiple lines between asterisks

Tags: regex

I am taking notes in an outline format that looks like this:

```
* Micro topic 1
** Microbes are small
** You can't see them!
*** Isn't that something?
* Micro topic 2
** I hope I like the teacher
*** She will be great!
** Micro is cool!
```

and want a regular expression that matches

```
* Micro topic 1
** Microbes are small
** You can't see them!
*** Isn't that something?
```

and

```
* Micro topic 2
** I hope I like the teacher
*** She will be great!
** Micro is cool!
```

so it would match from a line beginning with exactly one `*` up until (not including) a line beginning with exactly one `*`.

What I have so far:  `(?<!.)\*\s.+\n\*+.+\n\*+.+\n\*+.+`

But I need it to be dynamic.  The number of lines between each line beginning with a single `*` will not be consistent, and the text between them will not be consistent.

Comment: Looks a lot like org-mode. Perhaps they can help you find an answer over at http://emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Assuming regex in Python, the following should work if you looking for results of named group `b`. Note that in Python, `?P<b>` represents the named group `b`.

```
(?P<b>\* ((?!\n\* ).)+)
```

You can see the test results at https://regex101.com/r/jU1gX0/1